# Silverlight v5.0 SDKs

Tags: .net, silverlight-5.0

On opening my silver light application(Developed in VS-2010) in VS-2015, there are build issues due to missing of Silverlight v5.0 SDKs. Where can i get the SDKs for Silverlight v5.0 ?

Comment: Have you tried googling? The SDK is available the same way it always was, as a download from Microsoft. Silverlight was discontinued years ago and [reaches End-Of-Life next week](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/silverlight-end-of-support-0a3be3c7-bead-e203-2dfd-74f0a64f1788) this year. It's only supported on IE 10/11 on Windows 7 anyway. Are you really sure you want to deal with a completely abandoned product?

Comment: Possibly [duplicate question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34775493/where-is-silverlight-5-developer-runtime). All Silverlight releases are [here](https://www.microsoft.com/getsilverlight/locale/en-us/html/Microsoft%20Silverlight%20Release%20History.htm)

Comment: BTW you have to migrate. It's been 8 years since SL was discontinued. It doesn't run on any modern browser anymore

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos next year, but: I don't disagree

Comment: @MarcGravell oops, need glasses.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos I don't see any SDK on your linked page. I see only the runtimes. The SDK was on https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28359 but the link is dead now...

Comment: @TheincredibleJan that's what end-of-life means - neither the product *nor* the links are supported any more. The real solution is to migrate away from Silverlight. I suspect people with a (paid) MSDN subscription can find the SDK, as MSDN contains even DOS and Windows 95 downloads. For most people though, an MSDN subscription would cost more than migrating

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos I have MSDN subscription but can't see any DOS or Windows 95 dowloads there. The oldest dowloads seem from around 2004. There is no Silverlight. You don't know our software. :) I think MSDN subscription is way cheaper than the migration but we are already doing it. "end-of-life" should not mean that developer tools disappear months before it's date ("Microsoft Silverlight will reach the end of support on October 12, 2021"). Not important anyway. I just use the automatic build instead of my own for tests...

Comment: @TheincredibleJan it's not a few months. It's 8 years. The current level of support is clearly explained in the end-of-Support page. If your company bet that SL5 would still be available 5 years after it was discontinued, it was a bad bet from the start. `You don't know our software.` I know you use a discontinued technology. Just like the few remaining Flash developers will either have to migrate or shut down, you also have to migrate or discontinue your product. Just like Flash developers, there were at least 8 years to do so.

Answer (score 15):

I think you can use web archive to get the old (official) download link:

https://web.archive.org/web/20190126163602if_/http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/A/3/3A35179D-5C87-4D0A-91EB-BF5FEDC601A4/sdk/silverlight_sdk.exe

Source:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RamiAbughazaleh.SilverlightProjectSystem

Comment: Still works in 2022 thankfully!

Answer (score 5):

No matter where you find the tooling, you have to migrate.
Silverlight was discontinued in 2012 and [reaches End-Of-Life](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/silverlight-end-of-support-0a3be3c7-bead-e203-2dfd-74f0a64f1788) in *one year+1 week (October 12, 2021)*. It already reached End-Of-Support in January 2020. The reason you can't find Silverlight tools in VS 2015 and later is they were never released.

By now, SL 5 only runs on IE 10/11 on Windows 7. No other browser supports the plugins required for SL5 (or plugins in general)

The answer to [this possibly duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34775493/where-is-silverlight-5-developer-runtime) shows where to find the SL 5 Developer runtime and links to the [SL Releases page](https://www.microsoft.com/getsilverlight/locale/en-us/html/Microsoft%20Silverlight%20Release%20History.htm) which includes the last SL 5 download from January 2019.

You may be able to use them to keep your application alive for a while but you really have to start migrating.

**Migration options**

One option is to migrate to [OpenSilver](https://opensilver.net/), an open-source implementation of Silverlight on WASM that doesn't require plugins. This means it can run on all modern browsers and OS.[.NET Rocks show 1698](https://dotnetrocks.com/?show=1698) discusses OpenSilver and how to migrate. This is perhaps the easiest option, requiring minimal rewrite but also *not* offering all the benefits of a modern platform.

Another option is to [move to Blazor](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/web-apps/blazor) and specifically Blazor WASM. The APIs are *very* different from SL, instead of XAML you work with HTML, but that means you also get the latest browser features and Web technologies out of the box.

Finally, one could completely rewrite the application in a modern SPA JavaScript framework like React, Angular or Vue.

**A sudden change?**

Not at all. It wasn't even a sudden change back in 2012, when Microsoft announced they'd discontinue Silverlight. I had proposed Silverlight for a new project only a few months earlier, so I remember the embarrassment.

Disappearing SDK links? That's to be expected and may even be on purpose. EOL means the vendor has no obligation to keep anything online. Microsoft already explains in the EOL page that the runtime installer will be available only up to October 2021. There's no mention about the SDK, and in fact, removing the SDK download would be a great way to stop people from creating new Silverlight projects.

This didn't happen overnight either. [Even in 2016 the SDK was still available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34775493/where-is-silverlight-5-developer-runtime). That's 4 years after SL was discontinued. Microsoft really did phase Silverlight's removal over 8 years.

It's not just that maintaining downloads and docs *isn't* free. Those downloads and docs have to be migrated or even rewritten each time the web site changes, and take storage and bandwidth.

More importantly, Silverlight creates a security burden. A product's vendor has to release security fixes for any vulnerabilities found throughout a product's lifetime.

Any company that wanted to keep working with Silverlight had ample time to download all the tooling before it was removed.